# XNA/Mono Effect Throwing Runtime Cast Exception

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

*As a foreword, the exact same code works just fine in XNA, but Monogame throws an exception.  This likely requires someone familiar with the Monogame rendering pipeline.*

During the Draw section of my game, there's a ShadowmapResolver that renders out a texture that is the final calculated light pattern from a given light.  It's receiving an exception when rendering from what is essentially `EffectPass.Apply()` complaining that from somewhere within Mono theres an attempted cast from `int32[]` to `Single[]`.  Here's my code that calls it:

```cs
private void ExecuteTechnique(Texture2D source, RenderTarget2D destination,
                              string techniqueName, Texture2D shadowMap)
{
    graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(destination);
    graphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);

    resolveShadowsEffect.Parameters["renderTargetSizeX"].SetValue((float)baseSizeX);
    resolveShadowsEffect.Parameters["renderTargetSizeY"].SetValue((float)baseSizeY);

    if (source != null)
        resolveShadowsEffect.Parameters["InputTexture"].SetValue(source);
    if (shadowMap != null)
        resolveShadowsEffect.Parameters["ShadowMapTexture"].SetValue(shadowMap);

    resolveShadowsEffect.CurrentTechnique = resolveShadowsEffect
        .Techniques[techniqueName];

    try
    {
        foreach (EffectPass pass in resolveShadowsEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            pass.Apply(); // <--- InvalidCastException re-enters my program here
            quadRender.Render(Vector2.One * -1, Vector2.One);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Util.Log(LogManager.LogLevel.Critical, ex.Message);
    }
    graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
}
```

And here is the stacktrace:

```
at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.ConstantBuffer.SetData(Int32 offset, Int32 rows, Int32 columns, Object data)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.ConstantBuffer.SetParameter(Int32 offset, EffectParameter param)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.ConstantBuffer.Update(EffectParameterCollection parameters)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.EffectPass.Apply()
   at JASG.ShadowmapResolver.ExecuteTechnique(Texture2D source, RenderTarget2D destination, String techniqueName, Texture2D shadowMap) in C:\Users\[snip]\dropbox\Projects\JASG2\JASG\JASG\Rendering\ShadowmapResolver.cs:line 253
```

So it would appear that one of the parameters of my shader which I am trying to set is confusing monogame somehow, but I don't see what it could be.  I'm pushing floats, not int arrays.  I even tried changing the `RenderTarget2D.SurfaceFormat` from Color to Single for all my targets and textures, still gives the exact same error.

Outside of the function I gave, in a broader scope, there are no other parameters being set since another `EffectPass.Apply`.  There are multiple other effects that render *without error* before this one.

In case it helps, here's the source for the MonoGame Framework regarding `ConstantBuffer.SetData()`

```cs
private void SetData(int offset, int rows, int columns, object data)
{
    // Shader registers are always 4 bytes and all the
    // incoming data objects should be 4 bytes per element.
    const int elementSize = 4;
    const int rowSize = elementSize * 4;

    // Take care of a single element.
    if (rows == 1 && columns == 1)
    {
        // EffectParameter stores all values in arrays by default.             
        if (data is Array)
            Buffer.BlockCopy(data as Array, 0, _buffer, offset, elementSize);
        else
        {
            // TODO: When we eventually expose the internal Shader 
            // API then we will need to deal with non-array elements.
            throw new NotImplementedException();   
        }
    }

    // Take care of the single copy case!
    else if (rows == 1 || (rows == 4 && columns == 4))
        Buffer.BlockCopy(data as Array, 0, _buffer, offset, rows*columns*elementSize);
    else
    {
        var source = data as Array;

        var stride = (columns*elementSize);
        for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++)
            Buffer.BlockCopy(source, stride*y, _buffer, offset + (rowSize*y), 
                             columns*elementSize);
    }
}
```

Is this some sort of marshaling problem?  Thanks for your time!

Edit: P.S.: The exception is an `InvalidCastException` and not a `NotImplementedException`.

Comment: You might not want to share the project, but if you share I can try to help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps you or not but the only casting I see being done is the data as Array. I would bet that it is crashing on the line :

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(data as Array, 0, _buffer, offset, rows*columns*elementSize);
```

or

```
var source = data as Array;
```

Because they don't do any type checking before casting there. If that is the line it is crashing on it is because they don't seem to support non-array data values. I don't know this framework well enough to give you a solid answer on how to work around this. I would probably report this as a bug to the makers [here](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame)

Answer (score 1):

Try 2MGFX tool which optimizes shaders for monogame. [MGFX tool tips](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki/Effects-And-Shaders)

Comment: I already use this tool as a pre-compile shell command in my project configuration.  Thanks for the reference though.